# Cannot execute command as another user with sudo

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, sudo

I have this code, that is running on tomcat:

```
try {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh /home/user/script.sh");
    p.waitFor();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader errorReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String line = "";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line).append('\n');
    }

    while ((line = errorReader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.err.println(line);
    }
    return result.toString();
} catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

And my `script.sh` file:

```
#/bin/sh
echo 'USER_PASSWORD'| sudo -S -u USER ls
```

From command line, the script is executed excellent and I see results.

But when executing it from tomcat I get this message:

```
[sudo] password for tomcat: Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for tomcat:
sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt
```

I cannot solve this problem. I need your help.

P.S: Sorry me for bad english. Thanks!

Comment: As which user are you logged in when you run the script in the console? Note that your tomcat runs as user `tomcat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that the problem occurs because the Tomcat process is running with a different user (with different permissions) than the one you are using to execute the commands manually.

Usually, the tomcat user is named "tomcat" or something like "tomcat7", "tomcat8" etc. depending on the version.

To solve your problem, you have to add sudo rights for your tomcat user.

If you don't know the exact name of your tomcat user, you can check it with following command in the terminal while tomcat is running:

> ps aux | grep -v grep | grep tomcat

which will return something like this:

> tomcat9    26840  1.4 49.1 7920356 1904504 ?     Sl   Apr26 201:44 /usr/lib/jvm/java/bin/java...

as you can see, the name of the tomcat user will be in the first column of the displayed output.

Then, you add the sudo rights for this user and enable using sudo without requiring password by adding the following line into the file "/etc/sudoers" (you can edit it by entering "sudo visudo" in the terminal, this is some kind of shortcut for editing this file)

> tomcat9 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

Answer (score 0):

When I try this from the command line, it works when I supply the correct password.  (In your case, the correct password is the password for the Tomcat account; see `man sudo`.)

So I suggest that you check the following:

- Try running the exact same shell script from the command line.
- Check you have the correct Tomcat username on the command line and you are echoing the correct password:

  - As noted by [mprev0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1150936/mprev0), the Tomcat account name is system dependent, and may also depend on your Tomcat version.
  - I get a different error message when the username is incorrect ... but YMMV.
- Check that `ignore_local_sudoers` is not in effect in the `sudo` policy.
- Check that `requiretty` is not in effect in the `sudo` policy.
- Check that `visiblepw` is not in effect in the `sudo` policy.
- Check that the Tomcat user has an appropriate entry in the `sudoers` file.
- If you are running on a system with SELinux in enforcing mode, try disabling that temporarily(!)

See `man sudoers` for more details on `sudo` policy.  (Note that it is not clear from the documentation how the 3 policy options noted interact with the `-S` option.)

---

I would point out that what you are doing is not very secure.  Someone with shell access may be able to see the password in clear by running `ps -efl | grep echo`.  (If they run it at exactly the right time .....)

You could protect the password by using `Process` to give you a stream to write the password to from Java, avoiding the `echo` command.

A more important problem is that allowing the Tomcat user to run `sudo` commands places your system at risk if the Tomcat account is compromised or if someone manages to subvert your Tomcat server.  Imagine what might happen if a hacker was able to trick Tomcat into running:

```
   echo tomcat-passwd | sudo -S -u root rm -rf /
```